# Adobe Air - How to dim background when displaying a dialog (title window)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, adobe

Lets say I have the following mxml:

```
<view...>

  <s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%">
      <s:Button label="some label"/>
      <s:Button label="some other label"/>
      <s:Button label="yet another label"/>
      <s:Button label="one last label"/>
  </s:VGroup>

  <s:TitleWindow includeIn="abandon" id="dlgAbandon" title="Question">
        <s:VGroup horizontalAlign="center" paddingTop="8" paddingBottom="8" paddingLeft="20" paddingRight="20" gap="10" width="100%" height="100%">
            <s:Label text="Why?" color="{Constants.ChromeColor}" fontWeight="bold"/>
            <s:VGroup width="100%" gap="10">
                <s:Button label="reason 1" width="100%" id="btnR1"  click="onDlgWhyNotClose('reason 1')"/>
                <s:Button label="reason 2" width="100%" id="btnR1"  click="onDlgWhyNotClose('reason 2')"/>
                <s:Button label="reason 3" width="100%" id="btnR1"  click="onDlgWhyNotClose('reason 3')"/>
            </s:VGroup>
        </s:VGroup>
    </s:TitleWindow>

</view>
```

Now in my code I change the currentState to "abandon" so the dialog is displayed on top of the VGroup.

How can I dim the background behind the dialog (everything in the VGroup or even its parent - the view)? how can I undim it when dialog is closed?

Thanks :-)

Avi

Comment: Use `PopUpManager.addPopUp`. Check http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/PopUpManager.html

Comment: Thanks! I must be doing something wrong though. The popup pops nice and modal, but the background is not dimmed. I used the example in the reference you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution would be to add a semi-transparent background for this state, something like

```
<view...>

<s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%">
  <s:Button label="some label"/>
  <s:Button label="some other label"/>
  <s:Button label="yet another label"/>
  <s:Button label="one last label"/>
</s:VGroup>

<s:SkinnableContainer includeIn="abandon" 
                      width="100%"
                      height="100%"
                      backgroundColor="#000000"
                      backgroundAlpha="0.3">

    <s:TitleWindow id="dlgAbandon" title="Question">
        <s:VGroup horizontalAlign="center" paddingTop="8" paddingBottom="8" paddingLeft="20" paddingRight="20" gap="10" width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:Label text="Why?" color="{Constants.ChromeColor}" fontWeight="bold"/>
            <s:VGroup width="100%" gap="10">
                <s:Button label="reason 1" width="100%" id="btnR1"  click="onDlgWhyNotClose('reason 1')"/>
                <s:Button label="reason 2" width="100%" id="btnR1"  click="onDlgWhyNotClose('reason 2')"/>
                <s:Button label="reason 3" width="100%" id="btnR1"  click="onDlgWhyNotClose('reason 3')"/>
            </s:VGroup>
        </s:VGroup>
    </s:TitleWindow>

</s:SkinnableContainer>

</view>
```

Note that now the SkinnableContainer is included in the abandon state and not just the TitleWindow

Comment: Gr8 Philarmon, Just what I've been looking for! Thanks a BILLION!